# Why is the following generic constraint producing compiler error?

Tags: generics, types, compiler-errors, type-constraints

The following constrained generic function...

```js
interface Alpha
{
    member1: number,
    member2: string,
}

interface Beta
{
    member1: string,
    member2: string,
}

function convert<Source extends Alpha, Target extends Beta>(s: Source): Target
{
    return {
        ...s,
        member1: s.member1.toString(),
    };
}

const a: Alpha = {member1: 12, member2: 'hello'};
const b: Beta  = convert(a);
```

...is producing this compiler<sup>†</sup> error (where line `16` is the start of the `return` statement):

```
main.ts:16:5 - error TS2322: Type 'Source & { member1: string; }'
               is not assignable to type 'Target'
```

Of course if I'm doing the compiler's job and manually make a specific version of the generic function myself then it is working as expected without warnings or errors:

```js
function convert(a: Alpha): Beta
{
    return {
        ...a,
        member1: a.member1.toString(),
    };
}
```

So my questions are:

- **Why is the above definition not working as expected?**
- **And how to express such constraint in a different way so that it will compile?**

---

<sup>†</sup>Compiler version: `3.2.2`

Answer (score 1):

`Target`, being an extension of `Beta`, could have any number of new fields that you would not be returning - you're just returning `Source` with a changed field.

A possible fix would be to change `convert's` signature to match the implementation:

```js
  function convert<Source extends Alpha>(s: Source): Beta & { member1: string } {}
```

keep in mind that in any case you won't be able to do a spread from a generic type (relevant [TS issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727))

Comment: I disagree with the first half of your comment, because 1. the compiler could potentially have enough information (either through explicit type arguments or via inferable assignments, etc) to deduce the source and target types and make the comparison whether the two can be converted as it has been implement in the `convert` function, or 2. the compiler should complain if there isn't enough information available to it to figure out what to do.  OTOH I think the issue you linked looks very promising, I'll read it through in depth once I have enough time for it.  Cheers for your answer, +1.

Comment: the compiler can have the information to disambiguate the generics only _at call site_.In the function definition you're telling the compiler you can return any arbitrary subtype of Beta, but the implementation works otherwise: you're returning Source with a changed field. The compiler correctly understands that the implementation as written can not return arbitrary targets. This has nothing to do with inference, and it's the compiler just telling that that code is not returning what the definition tells.